# Daily and Weekly Newsletter using MailChimp or Mail()?

Tags: 7, emails

In my site I have 12K+ users and I want to send a `daily and weekly newsletter`. For this I want to use `mailchimp` module.  How to set a daily and weekly automatic newsletter?

Also is there any `rules` integration for `mailchimp`?

Or is there any better module for this?

Or should I use `mail()` function of PHP core?

Comment: Mailchimp has a sub-module called mailchimp_lists which provides a similar functionality. See [here](http://drupal.org/node/1870718) on how to create a list.

Comment: @develkar I am using the Mailchimp List + Mailchimp Campaigns. But I have to send it manually by creating a campaign and I can send one campaign only once. I want to create a template and want to send it daily or weekly basis.